# Trying to connect cluster to application

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

Im getting this error when I'm connecting my MongoDB Atlas cluster to my application and I am not sure what how to fix this issue as I have whitelisted all IP addresses as well. The code and the error are shown below:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());`    
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://surpol:mypassword123@cluster0.kiwls.mongodb.net/mydb123?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
        })
        .then(() => console.log('DB Connected!'))
        .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        });


    MongooseServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 54.156.90.92:27017 timed out
            at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/suryapolina/Documents/GitHub/Phaseify/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:828:32)
            at Mongoose.connect (/Users/suryapolina/Documents/GitHub/Phaseify/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:335:15)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/suryapolina/Documents/GitHub/Phaseify/backend/server.js:15:10)
            at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
            at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
            at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
            at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
            at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
          message: 'connection <monitor> to 54.156.90.92:27017 timed out',
          reason: TopologyDescription {
            type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
            setName: 'atlas-wpf52v-shard-0',
            maxSetVersion: null,
            maxElectionId: null,
            servers: Map {
              'cluster0-shard-00-00.kiwls.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
              'cluster0-shard-00-01.kiwls.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
              'cluster0-shard-00-02.kiwls.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
            },
            stale: false,
            compatible: true,
            compatibilityError: null,
            logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30,
            heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
            localThresholdMS: 15,
            commonWireVersion: 8
          }
        }
```

Comment: Probably have not whitelisted.

Comment: @D.SM I whitelisted the option of all IP's

Comment: Your cluster seems to be having some kind of an internal issue, if it's a free cluster  I suggest you make a new one, otherwise contact Atlas support to fix it.

Comment: @D.SM thanks you were right. Just made a new cluster and it worked. Wasted many hours for that lol, but you saved me an extra several, thank you.